# Does HAL_NVIC_SetPendingIRQ call the ISR to execute?

Tags: stm32, interrupt, cortex-m, stm32f4, stm32-hal

I am really new to STM32 world so I came across this while reading:

```
void HAL_NVIC_SetPendingIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn);
```

> This will cause the interrupt to fire, as it would be generated by the hardware. A distinctive feature
> of Cortex-M processors it that it is possible to programmatically fire an interrupt inside the ISR
> routine of another interrupt.

I got this from the book **Mastering STM32** (by Carmine Noviello page 208). From this I have understood that If we set this pending bit even from the main function, then the interrupt is generated.
So to try this out, I have written this code:

```
while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      for(int i = 0; i <10000000; i++);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      for(int i = 0; i <10000000; i++);
      HAL_NVIC_SetPendingIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
  }
}
```

along with this call back function

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_PIN){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15);
}
```

I have programmed GPIO_PIN_0 as source of interrupt and when I press the push button connected to PA0 the Interrupt works perfectly i.e. ISR is executed. To my surprice *HAL_NVIC_SetPendingIRQ* function doesn't generate interrupt. I don't understand why?

More Info:

- I am using STM32F411VET6 DISCO board
- I am using STM32CubeIDE to program the board

Comment: I have no experience with HAL, but I suspect that there is an additional layer of HAL which prevents execution to reach `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback`. Probably in that layer, there is some code to detect the GPIO pin causing the interrupt and it fails to detect the pin as the interrupt is generated artificially.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Tagli. I have found the function *HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler* inside *stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c* file. Defalult definition was like this:

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  /* EXTI line interrupt detected */
  if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_Pin) != RESET)
  {
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_Pin);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(GPIO_Pin);
  }
}
```

I got why the GPIO was not being toggled. It was the same reason you have commented above.
I have modified to prove it.

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  /* EXTI line interrupt detected */
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(GPIO_Pin);
  if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_Pin) != RESET)
  {
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_Pin);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(GPIO_Pin);
  }
}
```

Now the callback function is called when the `HAL_NVIC_SetPendingIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);` is being called